# Swap pandas dataframe having dictionaries with key and list of values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[image]

So the output that I need is the dataframe with rows like this {1:true, 2:true,3:false....}. If it is possible to do it without loops, that would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
f = lambda x: {k2: k1 for k1, v1 in x.items() for k2 in v1}
master_data_df[multiChoiceCols].applymap(f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gave the desired output. I just wish there was some vectorized function instead of applymap.

Comment: @SurajTripathi - Unfortuantely not exist.